# Reliably provide copyable alternative text for drawing while preserving spaces

Tags: tagged-pdf

Background: I wrote a package that typsets small icons created with `l3draw` which I would like to make accessible. More concretely, when the user copies text with some icons embedded, a replacement text for the icon should end up in the clipboard.

I tried two approaches:

1. adding an overlapping `\hbox` with transparent text next to the icon;
2. using PDF marks to add `\ActualText` into the PDF.

The problem with 1) is that I am not able to reliably control the spaces and the output and the construction using transparent text also feels a bit hacky. After compilation via using PDFLaTeX, the result I get from coping the output of the below MWE is `Foo descrbipatzion`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn

    \NewDocumentCommand{\myicon}{ }{
        \group_begin:
            \hspace { 0.05em }
            \hbox_overlap_right:n { \color_select:n { .!0 } description }
            \draw_begin:
                \draw_path_circle:nn { 0 , 0 } { 10pt }
                \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill } 
            \draw_end:
            \hspace { 0.05em }
        \group_end:
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    Foo \myicon baz

\end{document}
```

So, I'd probably opt for 2). However, the problem here is that I found it difficult to make the icon selectable so that the `\ActualText` is even copied. I found `\pdffakespace` when searching this site for similar problems and when compiling below MWE, the copied text is correct. But I wonder whether this is really the best solution considering the fact that I combine Expl3 with other commands.

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\myicon}{ }{
    \group_begin:
        \hspace { 0.05em }
        \pdf_bdc:nn { Span } { /ActualText ~ ( ~ description ~ ) }
        \hbox_overlap_right:n { \pdffakespace }
        \draw_begin:
            \draw_path_circle:nn { 0 , 0 } { 10pt }
            \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill } 
        \draw_end:
        \pdf_emc:
        \hspace { 0.05em }
    \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    Foo \myicon baz
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you are at the mercy of PDF viewer here. They decide about copy & paste (and have various heuristics which makes it difficult to find a always working solution).

I wouldn't use `/ActualText` for longer text, normally it is meant to replace one symbol. Also it isn't supported by all viewers and (as you discovered) sometimes ignored also by viewers which does support it.

I also wouldn't use `\pdffakespace` as it is not supported by all engines (tagpdf contains a reimplementation for luatex, but nothing for xetex).

Instead I would simply print something in small print into the background of some filled area:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\myicon}{ }{
    \group_begin:
        \hspace { 0.05em }              
        \box_move_up:nn{5pt}{\hbox_overlap_right:n { ~\tiny icon }}  
        \draw_begin:
            \draw_path_circle:nn { 0 , 0 } { 10pt }
            \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill } 
        \draw_end:        
        \hspace { 0.05em }
    \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
 
    Foo \myicon baz
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice solution! The only caveat is that the icons have no area that is always filled. They might be transparent even. But anyways, I will play with your suggestion a bit further and maybe add some transparency.

Comment: or make the font smaller ...

Comment: ... which reminds me of a [fun discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64828908#64828908)

Comment: chat discussions are always highly relevant ...

Comment: I just found that I can probably use a `coffin` or box positioned inside the `draw` environment and clip it away. The text will then still be selectable. The issue with the spaces remains ...

Comment: Just to make clear, I was not going to use `\ActualText` for longer text, just for one word, for example, the icon of a duck would copy to "duck". But I read again over lots of discussions about the correct use of `\Alt` and `\ActualText` and, to be honest, it seems that it is indeed maybe not completely against the spec but at least an edgy case.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that I could also use a `box` or a `coffin` to hold the description that I could clip away. So, this is essentially a follow-up to Ulrike's nice answer.

As Ulrike said whether spaces are added or not is obviously at the descretion of the PDF viewer. At least with Acrobat I found that if there is enough space between two boxes that hold text, a space will be added, but if the space it too narrow (or even negative), not space will be added in the copied string.

With the right resizing of the coffin, the issue with spaces could therefore also be addressed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn

    \NewDocumentCommand{\myicon}{ }{
        \group_begin:
            \hspace { 0.05em }
            \draw_begin:
                \draw_scope_begin:
                    \draw_path_rectangle_corners:nn { -10pt , 20pt } { 10pt , 20pt }
                    \draw_path_use_clear:n { clip }  
                    \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin { description }
                    \coffin_resize:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { 15pt } { 20pt }
                    \draw_coffin_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_coffin { hc } { vc } { 0pt , 0pt }
                \draw_scope_end:
                \draw_path_circle:nn { 0 , 0 } { 10pt }
                \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill } 
            \draw_end:
            \hspace { 0.05em } 
        \group_end:
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff  

\begin{document}

    Foo \myicon baz 

\end{document}
```

This would copy `Foo description baz` to the clipboard.

Comment: If you want real spaces between words, then yes you need something like \pdffakespace (or the activate/spaces option of tagpdf), but that is unrelated to actualtext for a graphic but is basically needed for all text. Without real space chars pdf viewer guess where a word ends.